# Form post on run time doesn't work - jQuery / AJAX / Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post a data on run time and I want to see this data same time. But I don't understand clearly how can I do. I think my problem is I could not choose the element correctly. What is wrong on my code ? Thanks all from now :)

> My Error is : Notice: Undefined index: **username** in C:\wamp\www\eva\check.php on **line 3**
>
> > Line 3 : **echo $username = $_POST["username"];**

form.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="formwrapper">
        <form method="post" action="" name="form">
            <input type="text" id="rname" class="inputa" name="uname" placeholder="Username">
            <div id="feedback"></div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

check.php

```
<?php

    echo $username = $_POST["uname"];

?>
```

myScript.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#feedback").load("check.php").show();

    $("#rname").keyup(function() {

        $.post("check.php", { username: uname.value },
        function(result){

            $("#feedback").html(result).show();

        })

    });

});
```

Comment: what is uname.value in js? Do you mean `$('#rname').val()` ?

Comment: Should I change it like $('#rname').val() ?

Answer (score 0):

You are POSTing the value as `username` and trying to retrieve it as `uname`. Rename your key in PHP:

```
$username = $_POST['username']
```

It's probably also a good idea to check if the value exists and return a nice error message instead of letting your code fail.

Comment: Or, alternatively, change the JS to say `{ uname: uname.value }`

Comment: Tomato, tomato. :P

Comment: I changed the code like you said but it's still same. Just error is changed :/